# Error using `extern template` in the presence of an explicit specialization of a class template member function

Tags: c++, c++11, instantiation, extern, explicit-instantiation

Consider a class template `S`:

<sub>[`s.hpp`]</sub>

```cpp
template <typename>
struct S
{
    void f() { /* ... */ }
    void g() { /* ... */ }
};
```

This class template also comes with a source file containing a specialization of `S<int>::g()`:

<sub>[`s.cpp`]</sub>

```cpp
template <>
void S<int>::g() { /* ... */ }
```

---

`S` is instantiated a lot of times as `S<int>`. In order to speed up compilation times by avoiding multiple instantiations of `S<int>`, I want to introduce an [*explicit instantiation declaration* (`extern template`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) in the header file `s.hpp`, and a corresponding *explicit instantiation definition* in the source file `s.cpp`:

<sub>[`s.hpp`] *(modified)*</sub>

```cpp
template <typename>
struct S
{
    void f() { /* ... */ }
    void g() { /* ... */ }
};

extern template struct S<int>;
```

<sub>[`s.cpp`] *(modified)*</sub>

```cpp
template <>
void S<int>::g() { /* ... */ }

template struct S<int>;
```

---

Doing so, however, results in the following compilation error:

```
<source>:11:14: error: explicit specialization of 'g' after instantiation
void S<int>::g() { /* ... */ }
             ^
<source>:8:23: note: explicit instantiation first required here
extern template class S<int>;
                      ^
```

I presume that the error happens because `extern template` is still considered an *instantiation*, even thought it is just a declaration.

**How can I achieve a possible compilation speedup by providing an `extern template` declaration in the client-facing header for `S`, while still retaining an explicit specialization of `S<int>::g` in the source file?**

Comment: Would hiding the `extern template struct S<int>;` in the header with an `#ifdef` _just_ when it's included in `s.cpp` do the trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the explicit specialisation in the header as well.

```
template <typename>
struct S
{
    void f() { /* ... */ }
    void g() { /* ... */ }
};

template <>
void S<int>::g();

extern template struct S<int>;
```

To distill the rules: a declaration of an explicit specialization must appear before an entity is the subject of explicit instantiation - definition or declaration. Because the explicit instantiation of `S<int>` recursively constitutes the same for `S<int>::g`, you need to declare the specialization in advance.

But let's just be thankful we aren't [on fire](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-8.sentence-2).